# Cannot install socket.io using NPM on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, node.js, installation, socket.io

This is a problem many people have had it seems, yet none of the solutions I have found seem to work. I am trying to install `socket.io` on Windows 8.1 using,

`npm install socket.io`

I get a ton of red errors that seem to take issue with some file,

> node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h

I have Visual Studio 2012 Express installed as per suggestions in other threads. Python version is 2.7.8, Node is 0.12, `node-gyp` is 1.0.3. The goal is to install `socket.io@1.3.5`.

What should I do?

EDIT: There are the errors

> ... Lots of errors here ... And then ...
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(457): error C2039: 'Dispose' :
>   is not a member of 'v8::Persistent' [C:\Users\
>   Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modu
>   les\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             with
>             [
>                 T=v8::Object
>             ]   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(458): error C2039: 'Clear' : is
>   not a member of 'v8::Persistent' [C:\Users\Ni
>   khil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_module
>   s\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             with
>             [
>                 T=v8::Object
>             ]   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(462): error C2039: 'NewSymbol'
>   : is not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Users\Nikhi
>   l\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\w   s\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see declaration of 'v8::String'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(463): error C2228: left of
>   '.As' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Nikhil\A
>   ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\b
>   uild\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(463): error C2059: syntax error
>   : ')' [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
>   modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(475): error C2039: 'NewSymbol'
>   : is not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Users\Nikhi
>   l\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\w   s\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see declaration of 'v8::String'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(475): error C2228: left of
>   '.As' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Nikhil\A
>   ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\b
>   uild\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(475): error C2059: syntax error
>   : ')' [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
>   modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(477): error C2039: 'GetCurrent'
>   : is not a member of 'v8::Context' [C:\Users\Nik
>   hil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules
>   \ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(5223) : see declaration of 'v8::Context'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(477): error C2227: left of
>   '->Global' must point to class/struct/union/generic t   ype
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
>   ient\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             type is ''unknown-type''   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(475): error C3861: 'NewSymbol':
>   identifier not found [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Ro
>   aming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\vali
>   dation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(477): error C3861:
>   'GetCurrent': identifier not found [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\R
>   oaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\val
>   idation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(518): error C2146: syntax error
>   : missing ';' before identifier 'request' [C:\Us
>   ers\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_
>   modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(518): error C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not supp   ort default-int
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\
>   engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(490): error C2065: 'request' :
>   undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Ro
>   aming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\vali
>   dation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(490): error C2228: left of
>   '.data' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Nikhil
>   \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
>   \build\validation.vcxproj]
>             type is ''unknown-type''   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(529): error C2039: 'NewSymbol'
>   : is not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Users\Nikhi
>   l\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\w   s\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see declaration of 'v8::String'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(529): error C3861: 'NewSymbol':
>   identifier not found [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Ro
>   aming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\vali
>   dation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(536): error C2039: 'NewSymbol'
>   : is not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Users\Nikhi
>   l\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\w   s\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see declaration of 'v8::String'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(536): error C2228: left of
>   '.As' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Nikhil\A
>   ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\b
>   uild\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(536): error C2059: syntax error
>   : ')' [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
>   modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(549): error C2039: 'New' : is
>   not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppD
>   ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\buil
>   d\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see declaration of 'v8::String'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(550): error C2466: cannot
>   allocate an array of constant size 0 [C:\Users\Nikhil\
>   AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\
>   build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(550): error C2440:
>   'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'v8::Local'
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client
>   \node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             with
>             [
>                 T=v8::Value
>             ]
>             No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(549): error C3861: 'New':
>   identifier not found [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\
>   npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation   .vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(555): error C2065: 'uv_work_t'
>   : undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\
>   Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\va
>   lidation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(555): error C2065: 'req' :
>   undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roamin
>   g\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validati
>   on.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(555): error C2448:
>   'NanAsyncExecute' : function-style initializer appears to be   a
>   function definition
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_mo
>   dules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(560): error C2065: 'uv_work_t'
>   : undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\
>   Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\va
>   lidation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(560): error C2065: 'req' :
>   undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roamin
>   g\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validati
>   on.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(560): error C2448:
>   'NanAsyncExecuteComplete' : function-style initializer appear   s to
>   be a function definition
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client
>   \node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(570): error C2039: 'request' :
>   is not a member of 'NanAsyncWorker' [C:\Users\Nik
>   hil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules
>   \ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.
>   io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(487) : see
>   declaration of 'NanAsyncWorker'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(571): error C2065:
>   'NanAsyncExecute' : undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\Ap
>   pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\bu
>   ild\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(571): error C2065:
>   'uv_after_work_cb' : undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\A
>   ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\b
>   uild\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(572): error C2146: syntax error
>   : missing ')' before identifier 'NanAsyncExecute   Complete'
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine
>   .io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(572): error C2059: syntax error
>   : ')' [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
>   modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(716): error C2661:
>   'v8::Local::New' : no overloaded function takes 1 argument   s
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-clie
>   nt\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             with
>             [
>                 T=v8::String
>             ]   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C2039: 'AsciiValue'
>   : is not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Users\Nikh
>   il\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\
>   ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             C:\Users\Nikhil.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see declaration of 'v8::String'
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C2065: 'AsciiValue'
>   : undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData
>   \Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\v
>   alidation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C2146: syntax error
>   : missing ';' before identifier 'value' [C:\User
>   s\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_mo
>   dules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C3861: 'value':
>   identifier not found [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roamin
>   g\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validati
>   on.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(817): warning C4267: 'argument'
>   : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible lo   ss of data
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engin
>   e.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(829): warning C4267: 'argument'
>   : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible lo   ss of data
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engin
>   e.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(832): error C2065: 'value' :
>   undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roam
>   ing\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\valida
>   tion.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(840): error C2065: 'value' :
>   undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roam
>   ing\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\valida
>   tion.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(840): error C2228: left of
>   '.length' must have class/struct/union [C:\Users\Nikh
>   il\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\
>   ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>             type is ''unknown-type''   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(858): warning C4267: 'argument'
>   : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible lo   ss of data
>   [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engin
>   e.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>   node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(873): error C2065: 'value' :
>   undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roam
>   ing\npm\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\valida
>   tion.vcxproj]

Comment: And the ton of red errors is, if you don't mind to share it?

Comment: They don't fit into the character limit for the question. I've added less than half of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I decided to start up a clean Windows 8.1 installation in Hyper-V and step through the process.

What I've come up with:

1) **Install Node.js**

2) **Install git**

- **CLI commands should be executed with administrator rights**
- Select "Use Git and optional Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt

  - [image: git-add-to-path]

3) **Upgrade npm to npm 3.x.x** (optional step)

Even though you've just installed Node.js it doesn't necessarily mean you have npm in version 3.

- **CLI commands should be executed with administrator rights**
- Run `npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade` in the command line interface.
- Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force` in the command line interface
- Run `npm-windows-upgrade` in the command line interface
- Select the newest version and let it install
- When it finishes the install run `npm --version` and make sure it responds with something like `3.x.x`

4) **Install Python 2.7.x**

- Go to https://www.python.org/downloads
- Click the button to download Python 2.7.x
- Run the installer.
- Select `Install for all users` - click next.
- Select to install in `C:\Python27` - click next

  - [image: python-location]
- Be sure to select `Will be installed on local hard drive` in `Add python.exe to Path` - click next

  - [image: python-add-to-path-01]
  - [image: python-add-to-path-02]
  - [image: python-add-to-path-03]
- Finish up the installation

5) **Install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop with Update 4**

Even if you have another version of Visual Studio installed on your system do install this as well.

- Go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44914
- Select `English` or some other available language and click `Download`
- Check `wdexpress_full.exe` and click "Next"
- Run the file downloaded. Begin the installation.
- If you're unable to start the installation, it means you already have the necessary tools for this step. Abort the installation.

6) **Now run `npm install --msvs_version=2013` and you should be able to reach the end without node-gyp throwing errors.**